# DatabaseError: DPI-1072: the Oracle Client library version is unsupported

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

hello i am using OCI version 8.0 and python version 3.6.5
i installed cx_Oracle-8.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

```
import cx_oracle

adding hostname, portnumber, servicename, username, password
```

evrything is good. trying to connect:

`DatabaseError: DPI-1072: the Oracle Client library version is unsupported.`

what version i must use?

Comment: The [cx_Oracle installation documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html) says you need Oracle client library 11.2 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value 64 and attempt to connect again. That should give you information on which library is being loaded. Share this information in your question if it is insufficient for you to discover the source of the problem!